# using and operator with where clause in java

Tags: java, sql

When I use

```
PreparedStatement ps = plugin.sql.getConnection().prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM playerhomes WHERE (uuid=?) AND (waypointname=?)");
            ps.setString(1, uuid.toString());
            ps.setString(2, name);
            ResultSet results = ps.executeQuery();
```

i get

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'waypointname' in 'where clause'

as an error
can anybody help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: I've checked the column and it's the same as waypointname

Comment: The message seems pretty clear: `Unknown column 'waypointname' in 'where clause'`. Double-check the table columns.

Comment: Check your table definition.

Comment: Can you share the table definition as well?

Comment: So error message says that table `playerhomes` does not have a column named `waypointname`. If you check the table and see a column by that name, then it's likely that your Java program is connecting to a different database, that does have a table with that name, but that table doesn't have the column in question.

Comment: There is another possibility: MySQL/MariaDB on Windows is not case sensitive while on Linux it is. Not only check whether the column exists but whether it's spelling is verbatim what you wrote.